# Problem with com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath

Tags: java, classpath, reflect

can someone please tell me what im doing wrong, because at this point it's getting really frustrating.

```
public List<Test> loadObjectsFromPackage(String url) throws IOException {
    return ClassPath.from(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
            .getTopLevelClassesRecursive(url)
            .stream()
            .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
            .filter(Test.class::isAssignableFrom)
            .map(clazz -> {
                try {
                    return (Test) clazz.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So what im trying to do is load an list of objects, which are assigned to a subclass, from a package.

Comment: Could you please specify the exception/error?

Comment: it just returns an empty list

Comment: It seems that the issue was caused by the library version. On an older version it seems to function